# Задача на Частичное применение функций в JS

Tags: javascript

На [сайте](http://dkab.github.io/jasmine-tests/?spec=6) есть задача, как я понимаю, достаточно простая для понимающих людей. Но у меня случился диссонанс, с одной стороны я её решил, а с другой стороны юнит тесты говорят что нет. Собственно мой код решения:

```
function partialAny(fn, ...args){
    return function(...param){
        let size = fn.length;
        args.map((el,index) => {
            if(el === undefined && param.length>0){
                let swap = param.map((elem,index) => {
                    if(elem != undefined){
                        return param.splice(index,1)[0];
                    }
                });
                args[index] = swap[0];
            }
        });
        if(args.length<size){
            args = args.concat([...param].slice(0,size-args.length));
            console.log(args);
        }
        return fn(...args);
    }
}
```

И мне пишет что я не прохожу 3 юнит теста:

1. должна подставлять несколько аргументов в partialAny(fn, a,
   undefined, undefined, b)
2. должна подставлять лишние аргументы в конец списка: partialAny(fn, 1)(2, 3) -> [1, 2, 3]
3. может вызываться несколько раз и результаты во второй раз не зависят от первого

Первый я вообще не понимаю, занялся вторым и третим. 
По поводу второго (и сразу же третьего)

```
function test(a, b, c) { return 'a=' + a + ',b=' + b + ',c=' + c; } 
var test1_3 = partialAny(test, 1, undefined, 3); 
console.log(test1_3(5)); // Итог вызова: а=1,b=5,c=3

function test2(a, b) { return 'z=' + a + ',x=' + b; } 
var test1_3 = partialAny(test2, 1, undefined, undefined); 
console.log(test1_3(523)); // Итог вызова: z=1,x=523

function test3(a, b, c) { return 'a=' + a + ',b=' + b + ',c=' + c; }
var test1_5 = partialAny(test3, 1)(2, 3);
console.log(test1_5); // a=1,b=2,c=3
```

Итого три различных вызова и три раза они сработали как нужно, т.е. третий юнит тест меня обманывает. Более того `test3` написан прямо как второй юнит тест и отработал правильно, поставил недостающие значения в список аргументов.

И сообственно вопрос что я делаю не так? Или это не со мной проблема? Может кто понимает, потому что у меня ступор. Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 0):

### Функция написана неправильно.

---

#### Сначала рассмотрим третий тест: *может вызываться несколько раз и результаты во второй раз не зависят от первого*

Простой пример:

```js
function partialAny(fn, ...args) {
  return function(...param) {
    let size = fn.length;
    args.map((el, index) => {
      if (el === undefined && param.length > 0) {
        let swap = param.map((elem, index) => {
          if (elem != undefined) {
            return param.splice(index, 1)[0];
          }
        });
        args[index] = swap[0];
      }
    });
    if (args.length < size) {
      args = args.concat([...param].slice(0, size - args.length));
      console.log('inside func', args);
    }
    return fn(...args);
  }
}

function test(...args) {
  return args;
}

var fn = partialAny(test, 1, undefined, 3);
console.log(fn(2));
console.log(fn('a'));
```

Как можно заметить, в двух вызовах результат один и тот же, хотя параметр был заменен.

#### Почему работает именно так?

Проблема в строках

1. `args = args.concat([...param].slice(0,size-args.length));`
2. `args[index] = swap[0];`

В них меняется изначально переданный массив, поэтому при последующих вызовах уже некуда вставлять новые параметры.

---

#### Второй тест: *должна подставлять лишние аргументы в конец списка: partialAny(fn, 1)(2, 3) -> [1, 2, 3]*

```js
function partialAny(fn, ...args) {
  return function(...param) {
    let size = fn.length;
    args.map((el, index) => {
      if (el === undefined && param.length > 0) {
        let swap = param.map((elem, index) => {
          if (elem != undefined) {
            return param.splice(index, 1)[0];
          }
        });
        args[index] = swap[0];
      }
    });
    if (args.length < size) {
      args = args.concat([...param].slice(0, size - args.length));
      console.log('inside func', args);
    }
    return fn(...args);
  }
}

function test(...args) {
  return args;
}

console.log(partialAny(test, 1)(2, 3));
```

Вместо добавления лишних параметров в конец - они отбрасываются.

#### Почему работает именно так?

Проблема в том, что к вызову функции не добавляются элементы, который остались в `param` после подстановки в дырки.

---

#### И, наконец, первый тест: *должна подставлять несколько аргументов в partialAny(fn, a, undefined, undefined, b)*

```js
function partialAny(fn, ...args) {
  return function(...param) {
    let size = fn.length;
    args.map((el, index) => {
      if (el === undefined && param.length > 0) {
        let swap = param.map((elem, index) => {
          if (elem != undefined) {
            return param.splice(index, 1)[0];
          }
        });
        args[index] = swap[0];
      }
    });
    if (args.length < size) {
      args = args.concat([...param].slice(0, size - args.length));
    }
    return fn(...args);
  }
}

function test(...args) {
  return args;
}

console.log(partialAny(test, 'a', undefined, undefined, undefined, 'b')('1', '2', '3'));
```

Как можно заметить вместо трех параметров, подставилось всего два.

#### Почему работает именно так?

Проблема в неверном использовании [`.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice). Данный метод меняет массив к которому применяется. В данном случае это `param`. Метод [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) **всегда** проходит по всем элементам массива. Применяя внутри него [`.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) можно заметить, что некоторые элементы могут пропускаться.

Еще одна проблема - проверка элементов `param` на `undefined` - она не нужна

---

#### Что со всем этим делать?

1. Не нужно менять исходный массив `args`. Достигнуть это можно простым присвоением результата `map` локальной переменной
2. Можно менять `param`, и то, что осталось после вставки в дырки `args`, нужно добавлять при вызове основной функции
3. Реорганизовать вставку в дырки. Самый простой способ использовать метод [`shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift). Данный метод меняет массив к которому он применяется и возвращает первый элемент.

Как это может выглядеть в итоге:

```
function partialAny(fn, ...args){
    return function(...param){
        var a = args.map((el,index) => { // сохраняем результат в переменную
            if(el === undefined){ // если в исходном массиве нет элемента
                return param.shift(); // вернем первый из param
            }
            return el; // иначе оставляем тот, который был
        });
        return fn(...a.concat(param)); // дописываем лишние параметры в конец
    }
}
```